# Convet leaflet map to static plot [r]

Tags: r, leaflet, maps

How to convert leaflet map to static plot so one can save the plot as pdf.

I know about `mapshot` function so one can specify something like `mapview::mapshot(m, file = "saveaspdf.pdf")`.

But suppose our leaflet object has more than 200MB therefore it is more efficient to convert it to static plot and Then save it as pdf/jpg.

How to convert `m` map created in code below to static plot?

```
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)

rm(list = ls())
URL2 <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_FRA_2_sp.rds"
data2 <- readRDS(url(URL2))


URL1 <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_FRA_0_sp.rds"
data1 <- readRDS(url(URL1))



data2@data <- 
  data2@data %>% 
  mutate(hdp = sample(rnorm(nrow(data2@data), mean = 100, sd = 20)))


paris <- data2[48, ]

# Define cut points for the colorbins
data2$hdp %>% max
data2$hdp %>% min
cuts <- c(50, 70, 90, 110, 151)

# Using quantiles by hand 
##########################

# Color: "YlOrRd"
cuts <- colorBin("Greens", domain = data2$hdp, bins = cuts)

m <- 
  leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
  addPolygons(data=data2, stroke = TRUE, color = "white", weight="", smoothFactor = 0.95, 
              fillOpacity = 0.65, fillColor = ~cuts(data2$hdp)) %>% 
  addLegend(pal = cuts, 
            values = data2$hdp,
            labFormat = labelFormat(suffix = " "),
            opacity = 0.85, title = "Model Predictions", position = "topright") %>% 
  addPolygons(data = data1, color = "black", fill = F, 
              weight = 2) %>% 
  addPolygons(data = paris, color = "red")
```

Comment: Take a screenshot? or see the `tmap` package?

Comment: and can you provide example using `tmap` package

Comment: See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/vignettes/tmap-getstarted.html#exporting-maps